# Resized NTFS partition, now it wont mount

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, filesystem-corruption

I have had a 1.5TB drive used as an external for 6 months or so, then I decided to put it in my linux server for network storage. ntfs was being crazy inefficient so I wanted to change the filesystem to ext4.

I used the ntfsresize command to reduce the partition to 650GB and that took abour 2 hours, then I deleted all of the entries in fstab like a guide told me too and created a new one the size of the ntfs partition, or, 650GB.

After I modified fstab the ntfs partition would no longer mount and when plugging it in to windows it says "This Hard Drive needs to be formatted". any ideas on how I can recover the data off of the drive? I have 600GB of free space on a different drive so I just need some way of copying them off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to find the lost partition and write it back into the partition table, as recommend by utilise [on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/exqly/resized_ntfs_partition_now_it_wont_mount/c1bra42)

Answer (score 0):

As a not for others, may have been better, in linux, to use Gparted to change the size, its GUI and strait forward.  Pretty much does all the work for you with the ntfsresize and such

Comment: yeah, I was doing all of this via SSH though, so gparted wasn't an immediate option.

Comment: well, i believe gparted is a GUI for parted which is a CLI tool, don't know if it integrates the ntfstools though